# error converting YAML to JSON Line did not find expected '-' indicator

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I am new to kubernetes I am writing a yml file to create a deployment. I am crating deployment by running this command "kubectl create -f backend-deployment.yml" but I keep getting this error:
"error: error parsing backend-deployment.yml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 16: did not find expected '-' indicator"

line 16 is - name: django-react-ecommerce-master_backend_1

following is my backend-deployment.yml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name : backend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: backend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django-react-ecommerce-master_backend_1
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the line below, you have an indentation problem there. `ports` should be at the same level than `name`.

```yaml
# indent the port bloc   
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: django-react-ecommerce-master_backend_1
          ports:
          - containerPort: 8000
```

Answer (score 0):

The hyphen should have no indentation:

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: django-react-ecommerce-master_backend_1
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8000
```